# User agent testing using Capybara not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I wish to run some of my tests using a user agent that will simulate an iphone. Currently I run my tests on FF, Chrome and also headless and I have the drivers defined as environment variables like this:

```
 when 'chrome'
  Capybara.default_selector = :css
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.run_server = false
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
  end

 when 'headless'
  Capybara.default_driver    = :poltergeist
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.run_server = false
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:inspector => true})
  end
```

So when I am running my tests I just enter BROWSER=chrome or BROWSER=headless and chrome or headless will launch. I wish to do the same using the user agent and I have tried the following:

```
    when 'iphone'
      Capybara.register_driver :iphone do |app|
      require 'selenium/webdriver'
      profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
      profile['general.useragent.override'] = "iphone"
      Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :profile => profile)
```

However when I try and run my tests like this: BROWSER=iphone, I get an message ' rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given (ArgumentError)'. So I have tried to fix this by adding the default driver and javascript driver at the start like so:

```
     when 'iphone'
      Capybara.default_selector = :css
      Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
      Capybara.run_server = false
      Capybara.register_driver :iphone do |app|
      require 'selenium/webdriver'
      profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
      profile['general.useragent.override'] = "iphone"
      Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :profile => profile)
```

but this just results in the default FF browser been launched. Does anyone know how I would get this to work or what I am doing wrong? I found this article: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/ and was trying to follow it but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not run server you should set:

```
Capybara.run_server = false
```

To set default driver to :iphone you should set:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :iphone
```

So the complete setup will be:

```
when 'iphone'
  Capybara.register_driver :iphone do |app|
    require 'selenium/webdriver'
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile['general.useragent.override'] = "iphone"
    Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :profile => profile)
  end
  Capybara.default_driver = :iphone
  Capybara.run_server = false
```

Note that it would be better to use [ios-driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/) or [appium](http://appium.io/) instead of Firefox with passed user agent

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrey. However when I used your suggestion I received the error: uninitialized constant Capybara::Driver::Selenium (NameError). Any thoughts? As regards your suggestion about using ios-driver or appium, currently our application is completely web based(not native or hybrid), but is designed to be used on mobile device browsers hence why I thought user agent testing might be a good option.

Comment: Interestingly I did not have require 'capybara'. I added it to my env file but I still get the same error. :-(

Comment: Managed to get this working, instead of:     Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :profile => profile), I changed to: Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile) and tests are now working, - thanks for your help Andrey

Comment: @user1523236 Sorry, I haven't noticed that